# Yii2 combine record query with count query?

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, yii2

General question about Yii2 AR queries. When querying an AR dataprovider, there is always a count query (by default) and a subsequent search query that gets the records.

I know it's possible to override the count query, but I'm wondering if there is an easy way to get the record count along with the record query (even if there is a limit clause, such as a paged result for a grid view) in the same query.

This is a very large table (will grow to up to 1 bln rows or more) and I'm looking at optimizations.  This could be a substantial performace boost if I could somehow combine these queries into one.

Using Postgresql as the DB.

There are a number of joins being generated through model relations

Comment: the first sql count query is needed to count how much models are in the results to be paginated. I think that you cannot avoid the first sql count query if you want to use pagination.

Comment: @FabrizioCaldarelli it seems that since we're doing all the table scans and the joins, we should be able to add a count query for a lower cost than doing the entire thing again.  Particularly if the primary table is being sorted, the whole thing is scanned anyway, even if the limit clause limits the rows returned.